# Does "Group Message" mean that all recipients would "see" each other?

Tags: ios, iphone, messages

I was wondering if I send a message to two (or more) people using iOS5, will the message automatically be a "Group Message"?

[image]

So, does that mean that in the above picture, John would know that I've sent "msg" to Peter, and Peter would know that I've sent "msg" to John?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience I always see all recipients in a group iMessage - so depending on if the author of the message chose email or phone numbers I see each recipient's information.

If I have that address/phone in my address book, then I get my address book's name for the contact, but even then, I can tap on the name and determine if an email or phone number was used to address the group.

On the iPhone, there is a group message toggle - but at iOS 5.1.1, it doesn't seem to matter whether this is on or off on the sender or the receiver - I still see everyone in the group iMessage. As far as I can tell, that switch doesn't do anything on an iPhone and isn't there to even help on an iPad / iPod touch.

Comment: Do you mean that even when both receiver **and** sender have that switch turned off, group messages are still sent? (along with the information that it *leaks*, information that this msg is sent not just individually to you, but to others as well)

Comment: Yes - I am seeing behavior like cc: in an email where all iMessage are clearly shown and not bcc: where only the sender gets to see who was invited to the conversation. No extra data leaks in the sense that if the sender sends to me using my email for iMessage, recipients see that email only and not the whole address book card for me if other data is present. My understanding is that group switch only works over SMS/MMS and not iMessage.

Answer (score -2):

No, according to [this topic](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3390300?start=0&tstart=0) on the discussionboard of Apple, if you send the message to multiple people, but they will receive it as single message.

If you want to achieve a group message, I suggest you use [group-sms](http://itunes.apple.com/app/group-sms!/id398189559?mt=8) (iMessages only!). Which will allow you to have conversations with multiple persons.

Comment: Btw are you saying that without that the default "Message" app is incapable of sending out group-sms?

Comment: No, it can. But the recipients will get it as a normal sms, not as a group sms.

Comment: Ok.. I'm not sure I'm understanding you here. How do we send a group sms? Are the instructions on http://www.trickyways.com/2010/11/how-to-send-group-sms-on-iphone-without-an-app/ correct?

Comment: You CAN send a group message (to multiple people), but the recipients won't know if it's a group message (because they receive it as a standard message)

Comment: Ah Ic, so were you saying that (even when all parties are using iOS-5,) with the default "Message" app, I can't send out a group sms that would be received as a group message?

Comment: Pretty sure that's wrong. It depends on their phones. I think I've had successful group messages before.

Comment: @jtbandes Do you mean that you have successfully sent a group sms using the default "Message" app and the receiver successfully received as a group message?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, but I don't know enough about MMS to give you a definitive answer without some research. Also, if everyone has devices with iMessage then you can definitely do a group chat.

Comment: I have seen many messages with multiple recipients on my iphone sent from straight iphone users who would have done nothing special to make a group.  I have also received group texts from non-iphone users and can see all recipients

Comment: @REDGAR and @ jtbandes, well the problem is that I want to send the same message to a group of people, however I do not want each party to know that it is a group message (i.e. I want the receiver to see it as an individual message). Is there some setting I can set to make it such that messages I sent are always sent individually?

Comment: @michiel - My experience is exactly the opposite of what you write. On my iPad for instance, there is no group SMS and I see all members of iMessages that I receive whether it's one or many. Might this be something that is different internationally than in the US? I'm baffled at the moment on why we're seeing different behaviors.